# Riddleform and Hadana's Climb

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have the card [Hadana's Climb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHadana%27s%5d%2b%5bClimb%5d) and [Riddleform](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRiddleform%5d) in my deck, if I add the +1/+1 counter on Riddleform while it's on it's creature form from my Hadana's Climb will it stay there until the next turn that my Riddleform changes or will the +1/+1 counter disappear after then end of turn?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, your [Riddleform](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRiddleform%5d) will keep the +1/+1 counters on it.**

Permanents don't generally care what [counters](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Counter_(marker)) are on them unless they have and effect that says they should care. So even when your Riddleform turns back into an an enchantment it will still have it's +1/+1 counters on it (even though those counters won't do anything).

One special case to note is that your [Hadana's Climb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHadana%27s%5d%2b%5bClimb%5d) can only place +1/+1 counters on creatures. So even if your Riddleform has already received a counter or two, you will not be able to place additional counters on it with Hadana's Climb (and then cause the transform) if it is not currently a creature.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, the counter will remain.**

From the Comprehensive Rules:

> 121.1. A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or interacts with a rule, ability, or effect. Counters are not objects and have no characteristics. Notably, a counter is not a token, and a token is not a counter. Counters with the same name or description are interchangeable.

You can put a counter on any **object** on the battlefield, as long as that object is a valid target when the ability/spell that puts a counter on it resolves. You can only put a +1/+1 counter on Riddleform using Hadana's Climb's ability **if Riddleform is a creature**, but any +1/+1 counters already on it when it stops being a creature will remain. It's worth noting that, since +1/+1 counters only have an effect on creatures, they'll essentially do nothing while Riddleform is an enchantment.